# Why is inv() failing?

Tags: julia

When I try and run the `inv()` function on the example from the Julia documentation (v1.0.3), I get an error.  The code is as follows (straight from the docs):

```
julia> M = [2 5; 1 3]
2×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 2  5
 1  3

julia> N = inv(M)
ERROR: MethodError: objects of type Array{Float64,2} are not callable
Use square brackets [] for indexing an Array.
```

It does work with `pinv()`, but I get some extremely small floating point values.  Any ideas why I can't get `inv()` to work for this extremely simple case?

Comment: I can't duplicate. Please restart Julia, and paste the following into the REPL `M = [2 5 ; 1 3] ; N = inv(M)` and report whether you get an error. My best guess is that you have somehow managed to redefine `inv` in your current session so that it no longer points to the function. For example, if somewhere previously in your code code you wrote `inv = rand(2,2)`, then you'll note you can now duplicate the error since `inv` now points to a matrix and not the function from `Base`. This shouldn't be possible from module `Main`, but is possible if working in a different scope.

Answer (score 1):

The error message suggests that you have previously defined a variable called `inv` which is a floating point matrix, and then try to use this matrix as a function, e.g.

```
julia> inv = rand(2, 2);

julia> M = [2 5; 1 3];

julia> inv(M)
ERROR: MethodError: objects of type Array{Float64,2} are not callable
Use square brackets [] for indexing an Array.
```

You can reach the `inv` function by restarting (and hence clearing the meaning of `inv`) or using the fully qualified name:

```
julia> import LinearAlgebra

julia> LinearAlgebra.inv(M)
2×2 Array{Float64,2}:
  3.0  -5.0
 -1.0   2.0
```